# Query machine for hostname

Tags: python, linux, bash

I want to be able to scan a network of servers and match IP addresses to hostnames.

I saw a lot of questions about this (with a lot of down votes), but none are exactly what I'm looking for.

So I've tried python's socket library `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)`. But this only returns results if I have a DNS setup or the IP-to-host mapping is in my hosts file.

I want to be able to ask a machine for their hostname, rather than querying DNS.

How can a query a Linux machine for their hostname?

Preferably using python or bash, but other ways are good too.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can remotely execute the command `hostname` command on these machines to acquire the Hostname

Comment: That sounds perfect, can you elaborate please?

Comment: since your host are Linux based machines they support a command called hostname which will return the hostname of the machines.

Comment: Is there a way to execute that command without logging in to the machine?

Comment: You either run it over ssh (which is logging in), or install a server (a web server, perhaps?) which runs something that returns the hostname.

Comment: @dan08 ssh machinename hostname. You need key based authentication.

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't quite cut it. I want to scan a whole network. And its possible I don't have an account on some machines.